# Problem after ubuntu installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, nvidia, uefi

I had a Windows installed on ssd - everything was fine. I would like to have second OS. I was going to install ubuntu. I splited ssd on three partition: windows os, windows application and ubuntu os. Reinstall Windows and then install ubuntu. It works but after shutdown pc and reboot, after few minuts I get no signal on my monitor. Motherboard logo doesn't present on screen, only help hard reset - normal reset didn't help.

When hard reset is done I get immediately grub menu. I try update graphic drivers on ubuntu. Secure boot in uefi is disabled. Changing outputs on graphic card is useless. Other linux distribution (elementary os) 
didn't solve problem. I think this issue is related with bios settings or grub but I don't know how to fix it. Any ideas ?

My spec:
Intel i5
Motherboard: z97-g43
Palit gtx 970

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [link](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/98373/en-us) nvidia-361 is the driver for Nvidia GTX 970

First uninstall the currently installed NVIDIA drivers. Boot the computer, when the GRUB menu appears ...

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and press the E key. Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line. Press F10 to boot the Ubuntu operating system.

When the login screen appears press Ctrl+Alt+F1. Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Now install the latest official stable NVIDIA drivers. Boot the computer, when the GRUB menu appears ...

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and press the E key. Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line. Press F10 to boot the Ubuntu operating system.

When the login screen appears press Ctrl+Alt+F1. Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
sudo reboot
```

Note : Maybe it is explicitly necessary to select the NVIDIA adapter in BIOS. When you want to use drivers 361, adding the PPA is not necessary. In this case the terminal commands you have to perform are these :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
sudo reboot
```

In case you have installed the nvidia driver from their site then uninstall it as per that instructions.Uninstall that driver by running, as root, `sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-361.28.run` and follow the on screen instructions

**Note : The solution I have provide has been tested on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Ubuntu 15.10 for two GPUs.**